# Is there a way I can set access to specific form elements?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I'm writing a custom ticketing system module for my company and I would like certain form elements disabled based on permissions. Is there a way I can do this **without** needing to make two separate forms (ex: user form, admin form)

I know for the items array in a menu hook, you can just set 'access arguments.' Preferably I'd like to just use the existing permissions I've already created for my module or even make it role specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [FAPI `#access` property](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access):

```
$form['some_element']['#access'] = user_access('some permission');
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was skimming through the documentation and didn't quite get how I would implement the user_access();. Makes sense now.